# Magento: invoice id in pdf

Tags: magento, invoice

How can I show invoice id in \app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Abstract.php

I don't need to show `getRealOrderId()` into pdf invoice, but I need invoice id.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are fine with the fact, that in the real life one order can have more, than one invoices? For example when there are partial payments and etc. It's easy to get a collection of all invoices for specific order.

Comment: Yes I know that, but I have a little specific shop and in my case this situation is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First be sure, that your order is loaded ... take a look at:

```
protected function insertOrder(&$page, $obj, $putOrderId = true)
{
    if ($obj instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order) {
        $shipment = null;
        $order = $obj;
    } elseif ($obj instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment) {
        $shipment = $obj;
        $order = $shipment->getOrder();
    }
    .....
}
```

So later you can use this snippet:

```
$invoiceIncrementId = '';
if ($order->hasInvoices()) {
    // "$_eachInvoice" is each of the Invoice object of the order "$order"
    foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $_eachInvoice) {
        $invoiceIncrementId = $_eachInvoice->getIncrementId();
    }
}
```

I referred, that forum reply: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/198222/#t393368

Good luck.